# How to apply RootLocusPlot correctly

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, complex, control-systems

I have to analyze the complex regions of variable `c` which is define obtained with `InverseLaplace` help in the form

```
Re[c] + Im[c] == -10 s^2 - (1/(2 Pi)
NIntegrate[1/Q[k, s], {k, -∞, ∞}])^-1;

Q[k_, s_] := 5 k^4 - 3 (-k 2 + s)^2;
```

I applied the `RootLocusPlot` on this polynomial, but I am not sure what I got. Is this complex plane of `c` variable? I need to see what will happen with `c` when `s` goes to $∞$ or $0$, but in my figure I can not understand that? Is there another command to plot diagram depends on complex solutions?

```
RootLocusPlot[
  TransferFunctionModel[Unevaluated[{{-10 s^2 - 5 k^4 - 3 (-k 2 + s)^2}}], 
                        s, SamplingPeriod ->None, SystemsModelLabels -> None], 
  {k, 0, 0.8}]
```

[image]

Comment: Since you didn't get answers [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43800/mapping-the-imaginary-axis-of-the-complex-s-plane) you are now asking a new question?

Comment: @Öskå I picked up the point just on the part of the question already asked. To take a look is it better for understanding because the problem is more complex that I thought.My previous question is large and consists of few parts. I didn't get any sign for further analysis.

Comment: You could have simply edit your last question since you are trying to answer it through this new question :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a polynomial $poly[s, k]$ in the complex variable $s$ and parameter $k$ and would like to see the loci of the roots of $poly[s, k]==0$ as $k$ varies, use the syntax `RootLocusPlot[1/poly[s,k],{k,kmin,kmax},FeedbackType->None]`.

Assuming I understood your question correctly, in your example the result looks like this.

```
RootLocusPlot[1/(-10 s^2 - 5 k^4 - 3 (-k 2 + s)^2), {k, 0, 0.8}, FeedbackType -> None]
```

[image]